# What is the difference between Cocoa Touch and Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

The two terms seems to be used inter changeably.

Is my understanding correct that Cocoa Touch refers to the framework that handles touch whereas Objective-C is just the syntax and language used to interact with this framework?

Much like WPF and C#?

Comment: Yes, although it doesn't handle just "Touch", it handles all aspects of UI - windows, alerts, controls, etc. It's "Cocoa Touch" to distinguish it from "Cocoa"; Apple's similar-but-different framework for desktop apps on the Mac.

Comment: UIKit, which is part of Cocoa Touch, handles all UI-related classes, but Cocoa Touch as a whole manages basically all classes available, so that also includes data types like `NSString`, that have little to do with UI ;)

Comment: I think `NSString` belongs to the `Foundation` framework and not the `UIKit` framework. correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Objective-C is just a platform-agnostic programming language, whereas Cocoa Touch is Apple's proprietary framework for writing iPhone/iPad apps, and this happens to be written in Objective C.